# SSLHandshakeException in mvnw verify

Tags: maven, pact, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to build [pact-workshop-Maven-Springboot-JUnit5/tree/step1](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-Maven-Springboot-JUnit5/tree/step1) but getting this error when I run command "mvnw verify":

```
C:\Users\MyUser\git\pact-workshop-Maven-Springboot-JUnit5\consumer>mvnw verify
Found "C:\Users\MyUser\git\pact-workshop-Maven-Springboot-JUnit5\consumer\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar"
JRE being used (logged by my modification in mvnw.cmd): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
Takari Maven Wrapper 0.5.6
Downloading Maven binary from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:72)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I've already added the certificate of Maven Repo to the cacerts file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts". Here is its entry in cacerts:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -list -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 79 entries

apachemaven, 14.Eyl.2022, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 5E:9A:A9:4B:5A:8A:1C:31:DB:1F:B5:E6:CF:E4:4D:B1:4C:AE:2F:5F
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven Central repository support only TLS 1.2 - [more info](https://central.sonatype.org/faq/tls-info/)

By the way mentioned project require JDK 1.8, so you must use JDK 1.8 at least - not 1.7.

With JDK 1.8 your problem will disappear.

Comment: Using JDK 1.8, now getting: "SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". But C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\security\cacerts file has the related certificate.

Comment: When I change maven-wrapper.properties and set repo as http://insecure.repo1.maven.org, I bypass certicifate error but now I get this: 

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.pact.workshop:product-catalogue:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom and '
parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10

Comment: OK after I installed the root certificate to the keystore, it worked. Thanks!